# Relationship between resistance, amperage, and propagation length of signal

Tags: electricity

n electrons sent into a wire of length L, and n/2 electrons sent into a wire of length L/2, diameter unchanged and wire material unchanged, does the "signal" of electron propagation reach twice as far in the first example, or, is the relationship not linear?

Answer (score 0):

If you force electrons into a metal, so an electron cloud, they will evenly distribute to reduce the gradient you just introduced,

So if your sending in the same amount of electrons, Varying wire lenght will have them spread to a different ratio, but as that ratio is dependent on how many electrons are in that wire to begin with, the relationship is not linear,

So the long wire would be something like "n Added / n Added + n wire length L"

And the short "n Added / n Added + 1/2 * n wire lenght L"

Comment: The number of electrons in the wire already are 1:1 though if you cut the wire in half? I'm thinking more this law, W = I^2*R, splitting wire into two halves decreases R by R/2, and, I with I/2, but, W with W/4, since I is squared. Ought to affect ability to propagate a signal.

Comment: Ah sorry, we get all kinds of questions in here, I was taking it more from physics. could you rework your question to clarify the exact example you want answered for, propagation length and a fixed number of electrons do not really make sense in combination, for wattage your treating it like a capacitive element with ESR, and I am confused how to approach that for "propagation length", propagation of which exact property. I was taking it as the average depth those new electrons would migrate down the wire during there addition.

Comment: I'm just thinking about the propagation length or how well a signal propagates. the exact context is here, https://www.docdroid.net/tolDQPw/the-reverse-of-photosynthesis-as-a-source-for-electric-currents-in-neurons-pdf, I suggest, somewhat heretically, building on Gilbert Ling (perhaps you know of him), that cells generate electric current simply by... burning reduced carbon dioxide and water, i.e., glucose in oxygen. Yes they do that for anabolism as well, but, so, besides that, also for axon nerve impulses, heart coordination, etc.

Comment: This is way down the path of an X-Y problem, what is the end goal your trying to reach with this question, your really leaving far to many gaps in what your asking. give an exact specific example, like how you might set up an experiment to confirm what your asking,

Comment: the goal, sending a signal from A to B. if the signal reaches as far in n, L as in 2* n/2, L/2, then segmenting it would not benefit. But, because of W = I^2*R, segmenting actually seems to decrease losses non-linearly